# Find a basis of a given subspace

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I have this subspace $S_1 = \{(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | -a + 5b - 2c - 8d = 0\}$
And I need to find a basis in it.

The subspace represents all vectors in the form of $(5b - 2c - 8d, b, c, d)$
And thus

$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} -8\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}$

spans $S_1$, but this is not a basis since the vectors are not linearly independent. So how would I find a basis?

Answer (score 0):

The family of vectors that you provide contains vectors that ARE linearly independent, and so that is a basis.

However, in general, if you have a family of vectors that spans a subspace, for that family to be a basis, the number of elements in that family needs to be the same as the dimension of the subspace, or equivalently, the matrix of this family of vectors (used as columns in the matrix) must have $n$ columns and be of rank $n$ (with $n$ the dimension of the subspace).

In practice, you'd remove vectors from your spanning family until you can't remove any more without breaking the fact that the family is spanning (ie, getting back a span with lesser dimension than what you want). That's how you can ensure both the linear independence and span/generation conditions necessary/sufficient for a family of vectors to be a basis.

PS: in your case, your equation follows the standard formula for a hyperplane, where that hyperplane is normal (perpendicular) to the vector of coefficients of the equation. A hyperplane is a $(n-1)$-dimensional construct for this reason (perpendicular to a single normal vector). Here, $n = (−1, 5, −2, −8)$ and $span(n) \oplus S_1 = \Bbb R^4$. This is why you can be confident that the basis of $S_1$ has $3$ elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Are you saying the basis I am trying to find is 3 vectors of shape 3x1?

Comment: You are in $V$ of dimension $n$. $\Bbb R^4$ of dimension $4$. The vectors of this space have will each be of shape $n \times 1$. A family of $m$ vectors of size $n$ can be represented as a matrix of size $n \times m$ ($n$ rows, $m$ columns). Here, you find $m = 3$ vectors for your basis, since $S_1$ is a hyperplane, so of dimension $n-1 = 4-1 = 3$. The matrix for which you should analyze the rank is thus of shape $4 \times 3$. It looks like the family of vectors you posted, but with big matrix brackets rather than big parentheses and curly braces.

Comment: In your case, you can express the first row $r_1$ of this matrix, ie $(5, -2, -8)$, as $r_1 = 5 r_2 -2 r_3 - 8 r_4$, meaning that that first row has redundant information and can be removed. You are left with the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, which is of rank $3$, you then know your family spans a $3$D space. Being composed of $3$ vector and spanning a $3$D space, your family is thus linear independent, and thus a basis of that $3$D space.

Comment: I see, but I don't understand why the first row of this matrix is redundant. Doesn't it hold important information about the subspace we're trying to span?

Comment: It does hold important information in the absolute, but here we're just calculating the matrice's rank (which is the dimension of the image of that matrix; the dimension of the subspace spanned by its column vectors). When running this operation, we realize the first row is redundant (ie, our total matrix has the same rank as the matrix with $r_1$ removed). Generally, to calculate rank, you'll want to row-reduce a matrix. You can look that up online if you don't know how. I'm pretty sure Khan Academy has a section on that.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. So what would a better basis for my given Subspace look like? Just the 3x3 standard basis?

Comment: Your basis is good enough: you can express any vector in your subspace as some linear combination of these three. Here's a potential improvement: if you want to make it orthonormal (have the vectors be perpendicular to each other, and each of norm 1) you can take a look at the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process.